# INNER JOIN has a column that used to be SEEK. But why is it not SEEK condition in HASH JOIN?

Tags: sql-server

TABLE CREATE, DATA INSERT

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN (
    A       VARCHAR(30)     ,
    B       VARCHAR(20)     ,
    C       INT             ,
    D       INT             ,
    E       DATE            
)

CREATE TABLE SUB (
    ProjectCode         INT             ,
    A               VARCHAR(30)     ,
    C       INT
    CONSTRAINT [PK__SUB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        ProjectCode ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE #TEXT_GENERATOR_1      (A      VARCHAR(30))
CREATE TABLE #TEXT_GENERATOR_2      (B      VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE #INT_GENERATOR_1       (C      INT)
CREATE TABLE #INT_GENERATOR_2       (D      INT)
CREATE TABLE #DATE_GENERATOR_1      (ID     INT IDENTITY(1,1), E    DATE)

INSERT INTO #TEXT_GENERATOR_1 VALUES ('Apple'),('Pear'),('Grapes'),('Mango'),('Yuja '),('Watermelon'),('Orange'),('Lime'),('Peach'),('Blueberry'),('Kiwi'),('Tomato')
INSERT INTO #TEXT_GENERATOR_2 VALUES ('Bear '),('Camel'),('Cow'),('Deer'),('Elephant '),('Goat')
INSERT INTO #INT_GENERATOR_1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
INSERT INTO #INT_GENERATOR_2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)

DECLARE     @START_NUM  INT = 1
        ,   @END_NUM    INT

DECLARE @S_DATE smalldatetime,@E_DATE smalldatetime
SET @S_DATE = CONVERT(smalldatetime, '2020-01-01')
SET @E_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1,DATEADD(YEAR, 4,DATENAME(YEAR,@S_DATE) + DATENAME(MONTH,@S_DATE)+'01'))

INSERT INTO #DATE_GENERATOR_1
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, NUMBER, @S_DATE),120) AS DT
FROM MASTER..SPT_VALUES WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE TYPE = 'P' AND CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(D, NUMBER, @S_DATE), 120) <= @E_DATE

SET @END_NUM = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @START_NUM < @END_NUM
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MAIN
    SELECT      A
    ,           B
    ,           C
    ,           D
    ,           E
    FROM        #TEXT_GENERATOR_1   A
    CROSS JOIN  #TEXT_GENERATOR_2   B
    CROSS JOIN  #INT_GENERATOR_1    C
    CROSS JOIN  #INT_GENERATOR_2    D
    CROSS JOIN  #DATE_GENERATOR_1   E
    WHERE       E.ID = @START_NUM

    SET @START_NUM += 1

END

INSERT INTO SUB
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
,           A
,           C
FROM        #TEXT_GENERATOR_1
CROSS JOIN  #INT_GENERATOR_1

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX__MAIN__A__B__E__C ON MAIN (A, B, E, C)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NIX__MAIN__B__A__E__C ON MAIN (B, A, E, C)
```

INNER JOIN QUERY

```
DECLARE @E DATE = '2023-03-10'
DECLARE @CC_E DATE = DATEADD(D, -1, @E)

DECLARE @TAB TABLE (PROJECT_CD INT, C INT)
DECLARE @CODE TABLE (PROJECT_CD INT, A VARCHAR(30), C INT)

INSERT INTO @CODE
SELECT  ProjectCode
,       A
,       C
FROM    SUB
WHERE   ProjectCode > 4

;WITH TBL_1 AS (
    SELECT  A
    ,       B
    ,       C
    ,       D
    ,       E
    FROM    MAIN WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   E BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -13, @CC_E) AND @CC_E
    AND     A IN (SELECT A FROM @CODE)
    AND     B IN ('Bear','Camel')
)

INSERT INTO     @TAB
SELECT          PROJECTCODE
,               A.C
FROM            TBL_1   A
INNER JOIN      SUB     B
ON              A.A = B.A
GROUP BY        PROJECTCODE, A.C
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
```

[INNER JOIN Plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA8AE.png)

Actual Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ0GZHxRp

INNER **HASH** JOIN QUERY

```
DECLARE @E DATE = '2023-03-10'
DECLARE @CC_E DATE = DATEADD(D, -1, @E)

DECLARE @TAB TABLE (PROJECT_CD INT, C INT)
DECLARE @CODE TABLE (PROJECT_CD INT, A VARCHAR(30), C INT)

INSERT INTO @CODE
SELECT  ProjectCode
,       A
,       C
FROM    SUB
WHERE   ProjectCode > 4

;WITH TBL_1 AS (
    SELECT  A
    ,       B
    ,       C
    ,       D
    ,       E
    FROM    MAIN WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   E BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -13, @CC_E) AND @CC_E
    AND     A IN (SELECT A FROM @CODE)
    AND     B IN ('Bear','Camel')
)

INSERT INTO         @TAB
SELECT              PROJECTCODE
,                   A.C
FROM                TBL_1   A
INNER HASH JOIN     SUB     B
ON                  A.A = B.A
GROUP BY            PROJECTCODE, A.C
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
```

[INNER HASH JOIN Plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUccA.png)

Actual Execution Plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcq-SeCT

The only difference is the HASH JOIN part. Why is column 'A' not included in Seek Predicates?
Does anyone know the difference?

The SQL Server version is 2016, 2022

For HASH JOIN, I need to know why column 'A' is not included in the Seek Predicates.

Comment: You should really fix your code layout, SQL isn't a fortran file specifiation

Comment: You're looking at wrong "node" in the Hash join query plan (second screenshot), it's still doing the `FROM    MAIN WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   E BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -13, @CC_E) AND @CC_E
    AND     A IN (SELECT A FROM @CODE)
    AND     B IN ('Bear','Camel')` thing there as you can see, the hash join comes later

Comment: Does it mean that the space is weird when writing SQL script or does it mean that the writing of the inquiry is wrong? @siggemannen

Comment: As you said, hash join is another node. But only INNER JOIN and INNER 'HASH' JOIN are different. I wonder why column A is not included in Seek Predicates.. @siggemannen

Comment: Because it wants to perform things in different style depending on JOIN later. But it's impossible to work with screenshots to explain anything. Please attach the real plans through https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I attached the actual action plan. INNER JOIN : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJ0GZHxRp, INNER HASH JOIN : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcq-SeCT. Thank you for your good point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are using a table variable here at all. You could just as easily use a normal join in the main query.

```sql
INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT
  PROJECTCODE,
  A.C
FROM MAIN A
INNER JOIN SUB B ON A.A = B.A
WHERE A.E BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -13, @CC_E) AND @CC_E
  AND A.A IN (SELECT SUB.A FROM SUB WHERE SUB.ProjectCode > 4)
  AND A.B IN ('Bear','Camel')
GROUP BY
  PROJECTCODE,
  A.C
```

But at the very least, you should add an index to your table variable

```sql
DECLARE @CODE TABLE (
  PROJECT_CD INT, A VARCHAR(30), C INT,
  INDEX IX CLUSTERED (A, PROJECT_CD)
)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/H-ZmGWN5)

Comment: You are right, but even so, column 'A' is not included in the Seek Predicates in INNER HASH JOIN. Your good point will help me in the future, but my question is why column 'A' is not included in Seek Predicates in INNER HASH JOIN.